# Other application pops up on my WinForm app

Tags: events, popup

I'm facing problems with my Windows Forms app. I have a couple of timers in it and I want to stop them right after another Windows application pops up.

Is there any event which can help me to catch that pop-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Deactivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the `Form`. That will fire when your window looses focus.

The event will fire whenever your form looses focus to another window, whether that window is part of your application or a different application. You will have to add some other code to determine if the new focused window is part of your application or not.

To determine whether the newly focused window is one of the windows owned by your application you could use the [OpenForms collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2962453 - great! If it answered your question, please mark it ;)